# If input contains anythign other than a letter, show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a simple first/last name form. When submitted I want to check that only letters have been used and if not, display an error div.

For example:

```
if ('#input-32' ) {
    /* contains anything other than letters */
    $("#error").show(); 
}
```

Comment: Please research on jQuery Validator

Comment: also keep in mind: There are names which have non letters in them. Also consider checking for ÄÖÜ or other special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should show the error element if input contains anything other than letters:

```
if ($('#input-32').val().match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
  /* contains anything other than letters */
  $("#error").show(); 
}
```

Comment: Great. Please consider accepting this as your answer.

Comment: Just noticed that this still allows whitespace - how would you adapt the regex to prevent this?

Comment: @Harry please example at https://jsfiddle.net/g21f8xzt/. Any whitespace character will trigger the error to show as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex - [Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#firstname');

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
 const val = e.target.value;
 const isLetter = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(val);
 console.log(isLetter);
        // if( isLetter ){ ... }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstname">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#error").hide();
  $("#nameField").on("change", function(){
    var nameSub = $('#nameField').val();
    if(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(nameSub)){
      $("#error").hide();
    }
    else{
      $("#error").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="name" id="nameField"/>
<div id="error">error</div>
```